# Is it possible on TeamCity to build a module against all agents when a VCS Trigger is met?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I would like a module to be run by **all agents** when a VCS trigger condition is met.

Is this possible?

Comment: out of interest, what is the agent doing? is it building code or deploying something?

Comment: The job simply updates from svn, other modules include files within it - hence I want it everwhere an agent is configured.

Comment: The module/configuration to be run next (not the svn update job) should be able to do that (update svn prior to running) without your dedicated job?

Comment: Sorry don't follow you:  Quote 'module/configuration to be run next should be able to do that' - how/where?

Comment: ok, sorry to answer a question with a question but why do you have a job that `simply updates from svn` ?

Comment: I would make libraries from code and use them as dependency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can do this is by adding a Schedule Trigger which has an option to run on all agents.

Comment: How can do that if the build needs to be run manually and not at particular date?

Comment: If you click the '...' next to Run for the build, there's a select box for 'Agent' in the 'General' tab. The last option lets you run on all enabled compatible agents.

Answer (score 0):

Having looked into it, as far as I can see, not directly,

the behaviour could potentially be achieved by using the command line remote runner plugin,(http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/Command+Line+Remote+Run+Tool) through a seperate build configuration linked to the VCS to detect the changes, calling the Remote Run tool from a command line build step to build the project on each required agent.

Further research into the Command Line Remote Run tool would be required to confirm this is possible.

There may also be some functionality allowing this in the REST API, although my look through the documentation didn't show anything up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had much luck working on alternative solutions?

I've created a build configuration to update our source managed third party referenced assemblies directory and this is a snapshot dependency on most if not all build configurations. When I update this directory with a new or more recent assembly, I'll too would like this configuration to be run on all build agents.

At the moment, I've simply duplicated the configuration and bound each to a specific agent. It adds management overhead, but has temporarily resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could install this plugin and specify the list of agent names and it will run once per "value" in the matrix.

https://github.com/presidentio/teamcity-matrix-build-plugin